# Executing a CAML query will return this error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"

Tags: development, csom, error, caml-query, caml

I have the following code inside our console application, to loop through a list of number and query the SharePoint list which is inside a modern communication site:

```
foreach (var r in allrequests.requests)

{

    Console.WriteLine("Entered foreach ");

    Console.WriteLine("RequestID= "+ r.id);

    CamlQuery camlQuery2 = new CamlQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("CAML initiaited" + r.id);

    r.id = "1";

    camlQuery2.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='RiskRequestIDNew'/><Value Type='Text'>" + r.id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    Console.WriteLine("CAML ViewXML" + r.id);

    ListItemCollection oListItems2 = context.Site.RootWeb.GetList(RisksiteUrl + "Lists/RiskManagement/").GetItems(camlQuery2);

    Console.WriteLine("CAML GetItems" + r.id);

    context.Load(oListItems2);

    Console.WriteLine("Context load" + r.id);

    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("execute second CAML");
```

Now when the code reach `context.ExecuteQuery();` it will raise this error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: index

Comment: Try adding `context.ExecuteQuery();` after `foreach` loop.

Comment: @GaneshSanap same error i am unable to execute the CAML query.. i checked the internal names of the list columns and the list and they are valud

Comment: First try getting list like: `List oList = context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("RiskManagement");` Then get list items from `ListItemCollection oListItems2 = oList.GetItems(camlQuery2);`

Comment: @GaneshSanap did not have any change

Comment: @GaneshSanap i almost spent 2 days on this .. i am planning to opne a case with MS

Comment: Take a look into [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caml-query-to-retrieve-the-items-from-a-list-using-csom1)